# Mongodb count rows per week

Tags: mysql, mongodb, collections, meteor

I used mysql for a long time. No I try to learn Mongodb. I Build a meteor application. For this applications I use collections. I like two count the rows per week in the collections. In mysql the command will ben

```
SELECT WEEKOFYEAR(datum) AS weekno, COUNT(1) AS signups FROM klussenblok GROUP BY WEEKOFYEAR(datum)
```

Can you help me with the same command for mongodb.

Thank you

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/

Comment: I found that as well, but how to group per week from a datefield

Comment: Use `$week`.  See  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#date-operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the mongodb-aggregation package in from atmosphere

```
mrt add mongodb-server-aggregation
```

Then use an aggregation method (if your date is stored in `datefield`)

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        $group : {
            _id: {
                $week: "$createdAt"
            }
        },
        count: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
]

var results = Meteor.users.aggregate(pipeline);

console.dir(results) //An array of weeks and signups in them.
```